# What are the similarities and differences between Java Annotations and C# Attributes?

Tags: c#, java, attributes, annotations, custom-attributes

I have a Java library I'm considering porting to C#.  The Java library makes extensive use of annotations (at both build time and run time.)

I've never used C# attributes, but understand that they are the rough equivalent of Java annotations.

If I proceed with the port using attributes to replace annotations, what do I need to know?  What's going to be the same?  Different?  What's going to bite me?

Answer (score 32):

Control over when your metadata is made accessible is different between the two languages.

**Java provides the [java.lang.annotation.Retention](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html) annotation and [java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) enum** to control when annotation metadata is accessible.  The choices vary from `Runtime` (most common - annotation metadata retained in class files), to `Source` (metadata discarded by compiler).  You tag your custom annotation interface with this - for example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.CLASS)
public @interface TraceLogging {
  // etc
}
```

would allow you to reflect on your custom `TraceLogging` annotation at runtime.

**C# uses the [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) attribute** that is driven from compile time symbols.  So the analogous example in C# is:

```
[Conditional("TRACE")]
public class TraceLoggingAttribute : Attribute
{
  // etc
}
```

which would cause the compiler to spit out the metadata for your custom `TraceLogging` attribute only if the `TRACE` symbol was defined.

*NB. attribute metadata is available at runtime by default in C# - this is only needed if you want to change that.*

Comment: +1: Retention into runtime will be important for the port.  thanks.

Comment: yw.  Note that as per my last edit, you will be able to reflect on your custom C# attribute if you do nothing.  This mechanism allows you to turn off that default behaviour, which is probably of limited utility to be honest.

Answer (score 20):

One important aspect of Java annotations which I haven't looked at in detail yet: you can write code which uses annotations within javac (as of Java 6, I believe) [as a form of metaprogramming](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html).

[PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) allows something similar, admittedly.

(That's far from the only difference, but it's all I have time for right now.)

Comment: While I've eyed apt, I don't actually use the APT API - my code uses reflection (and a doclet) to do its work (as opposed to using APT to generate an set of intermediate stuff during the build.)  So, I think I'm not concerned about this missing capability.  Keep 'em coming :)

Comment: Jon - just pinging you to let you know that there's a 100 point bounty on this question - if you have more time to spend giving a more complete answer (and the points are worth it) - I'd certainly welcome that :).  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I'll see if I can can find time to look into it more. I may well not have time though :(

Answer (score 16):

**One interesting difference is that C# allows module and assembly level attributes.**  These are applied to your module or assembly and are available via reflection in the normal way.  Java does not provide reflection on a jar file, so jar level annotations are not possible.

In fact this is quite common as Visual Studio a file called `AssemblyInfo.cs` at the root project level which contains, for example:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.2.3.4")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitleAttribute("My project name blah blah")]
...
```

There is no equivalent jar level annotation in Java (although since jdk5, there is a little used package level annotation mechanism - thanks to [mmeyers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13531/mmyers) for pointing that one out)

Comment: There actually are package-level annotations in Java: see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#97373.

Comment: These are not applied to all public types! They apply only to the assembly or module.

Answer (score 3):

Following up to what Jon said...

Both Java 5 and Java 6 allow metaprogramming. Java 5 uses a separate apt tool; Java 6 integrates it into the compiler. (Though the Java 5 apt is still available in Java 6)

Unfortunately each uses a different API.

I'm currently using the Java 5 API for my Bean annotations

See http://code.google.com/p/javadude/wiki/Annotations for an example
(NOTE: I'm currently making some major updates, some of which change the API.)

Very cool stuff...
-- Scott