# Java Annotation C# equivalent

Tags: c#, java, .net, annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the similarities and differences between Java Annotations and C# Attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553857/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-java-annotations-and-c-sharp-a)

Currently we are translating an Java project into C#, but we're having problems finding out what the C# equivalent is for Java annotation. How do we write the exact same thing as this java code into C#?:

```
public @interface LatitudeAnnotation {
    public String author() default "Themaopdracht 7 tester";
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/) are to C# what annotations are to Java

Comment: This link is no longer valid, I found the following reference useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/.