# Are java annotations the same thing with C# attributes? What is the equivalent in C++?

Tags: c#, java, c++, attributes, annotations

Are java annotations the same thing with C# attributes? What is the equivalent in C++?

I found the solution of the first part of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553857/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-java-annotations-and-c-sharp-a). But what about C++? I think these kinds of mechanism are not possible in C++ because they request reflection and reflection doesn't exists in C++. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are a form of *metadata* on the Java class and contained members/methods. They are distinct from compiler-scope keywords since they can persist in the compiled class and (as you've noted) available via reflection. I don't believe there's any equivalent in C++.

Comment: [C++11 added override and final](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final).

Comment: Are those metadata on the compiled code, or (more simply) compiler directives ?

Comment: Yes, they are only compiler directives, but where meant to behave like Java annotations in some respect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some attributes with gcc, see [Declaring Attributes of Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

But this is very specific and not portable and not as flexible or extendable as Java annotations.

Although, it seems you can write compiler plugins, which extend the set of recognized attributes

> GCC plugins may provide their own attributes.